# Young Sheldon, Season 1 Episode 11 "I was once visited by nine"

Tags: reference, the-big-bang-theory, young-sheldon

The entire quote, after young Sheldon is awakened from his binary meaning to the universe dream, Jim Parsons speaks the words:

"I was once visited by Nine when I had chickenpox.
He was a lot less funny than he thought he was."

I think "visited by Nine" and "a lot less funny" probably references something because it's so specific, but I have no idea what that's referencing and neither Google nor Urban Dictionary was any help.

Comment: Isn't 9 in binary 1001? Kinda like LOL?

Comment: I thought it's that he got chickenpox by **age** nine and it wasn't funny

Comment: Can you find the actual phrase somewhere?

Comment: @Joachim full script in https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=858&t=41661

Comment: Reference to Sesame Street?

Comment: @user7294900  That's not what he said.   Sheldon had strange dreams in TBBT.  It was one of the things they did and they revisited that in this episode in Young Sheldon where he has a conversation with to the binary numbers 1 and 0.   Jim Parsons very clearly says "I was visited by Nine".   It's an odd line and I assumed it referenced something because often writers will put an easter egg in a somewhat random line like that one.   Maybe it references nothing, but that's why I asked.   To people voting to close, is asking if something might be an easter egg discouraged?

Answer (score 3):

In the episode Sheldon is visited by two characters - One and Zero - who claim to be "the binary code underlying everything" and are about to tell Sheldon the Secret of the Universe, before they are disturbed. We can reasonably conclude that they are products of Sheldon's imagination and/or hallucinatory dreams.

Sheldon says that he never hears from them again, but does encounter "Nine", who we can assume from his name is a similar dreamed character, especially since he arrives when Sheldon is sick with chickenpox, a time when children tend to have unusual dreams.